# Elasticsearch- Add type and id to CreateIndexResponse

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

While creating index one can use the:

```
CreateIndexResponse createIndexRequestBuilder = client().admin().indices()
                .prepareCreate(INDEX_NAME)
                .setSource(XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
                        .startObject()
                        .field("title", "My Title 1")
                        .endObject()
                )
                .setSettings(
                        Settings.settingsBuilder()
                                .put("index.number_of_shards", 2)
                                .put("index.number_of_replicas", 2)
                )
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
```

However how can I setup the index `type`, and the `id` of this one source object with only one `title` field?

**EDIT**

When changed as recommended to add two documents I keep getting the `IndexAlreadyExistsException` error:

```
CreateIndexResponse createIndexRequestBuilder = client().admin().indices()
        .prepareCreate(INDEX_NAME)
        .setSettings(
                Settings.settingsBuilder()
                        .put("index.number_of_shards", 2)
                        .put("index.number_of_replicas", 2)
        )
        .execute()
        .actionGet();

IndexResponse response1 = client().prepareIndex(INDEX_NAME, BOOK_TYPE_NAME, "id1")
        .setSource(XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
                .startObject()
                .field("title", "Clean COde")
                .endObject()
        )
        .setRouting("route1")
        .get();
IndexResponse response2 = client().prepareIndex(INDEX_NAME, BOOK_TYPE_NAME, "id2")
        .setSource(XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
                .startObject()
                .field("title", "Learn Scala")
                .endObject()
        )
        .setRouting("route2")
        .get();
```

It seems that the `prepareCreate` and `prepareIndex` both create indexes. But not allow to setup all required preferences meaning:

- shard nr
- replica nr
- index name
- index type
- new document id.
  -

**How this can be done?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you have given, it appears you are trying to use the client admin API for creating indexes to try and create an index AND index a document at the same time.  The admin().indices() API is for administrating indexes as a whole, not for indexing, creating, deleting, etc documents into/from indexes.

You can create your index using your code, ripping out the setSource portion.

In order to actually index a document, see here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-index.html

Specifically, this chunk of code:

```
IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet", "1")
    .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                .startObject()
                    .field("user", "kimchy")
                    .field("postDate", new Date())
                    .field("message", "trying out Elasticsearch")
                .endObject()
              )
    .get();
```

Arguments 1 and 2 of prepareIndex() are the index name and document type respectively, while the optional 3rd argument is for supplying an ID, which is exactly what you are looking for.

How I would do it is this:

```
IndicesExistsResponse res = client.admin().indices().prepareExists("twitter").get();

if (!res.isExists()) {
    System.out.println("index doesn't exist, creating");
    CreateIndexResponse createIndexRequestBuilder = client.admin().indices()
            .prepareCreate("twitter")
            .setSettings(
                    Settings.settingsBuilder()
                            .put("index.number_of_shards", 2)
                            .put("index.number_of_replicas", 2)
            )
            .get()
}

IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet", "1")
    .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                .startObject()
                    .field("user", "kimchy")
                    .field("postDate", new Date())
                    .field("message", "trying out Elasticsearch")
                .endObject()
              )
    .get();
```

Comment: But when I chage it like that (see EDIT of the question) I keep getting the ` IndexAlreadyExistsException` error.

Comment: Just as the exception says, if you keep executing your code, you are trying to add an index that already exists in your cluster.  i.e. If you try to make a "twitter" index in your code, and then keep running it, you will get an exception if you keep trying to run it.  You need to delete the index before running your code again, or do a check to see if the index already exists.  ``IndicesExistsResponse res = client.admin().indices().prepareExists("twitter").get();``

Comment: I did not have the index when I called the code form the EDIT in the question   . It seems that the call to `prepareCreate` and `prepareIndex`  both create the same  index. How am I supposed to add those both document in that case?

Comment: Can you edit your post providing the complete answer code for the following index creation with setting up: **index name, index type, replica number, shard number.** So that I can accept the answer